# I'm trying to make a skybox, but I must be missing something fundamental

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js

I am trying to make a skybox, and every tutorial I have tried will not work. I thought I could make an array and pass it as a param for the material like I saw in an earlier example, but the method has apparently changed to TextureLoader() since then. Below is my code:

```
// Adds a skybox around the content
    var skyBoxMaterials = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( 'images/skybox/sky1.jpg') }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( 'images/skybox/sky2.jpg') }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( 'images/skybox/sky3.jpg') }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( 'images/skybox/sky4.jpg') }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( 'images/skybox/sky5.jpg') }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( 'images/skybox/sky6.jpg') }),
  ];
  var skyBoxGeom = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10000, 10000, 10000, 1, 1, 1);
    skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( skyBoxGeom, skyBoxMaterials );
    skyBox.position.set(0, 25.1, 0);
    scene.add( skyBox );
```

When I run it currently, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined" in the console infinitely looping until the server is killed. I could not find the exact answer in the examples, docs, or in another question, here. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: After some more digging, I finally found the example I needed in the docs under cubeGeometry, but it still does not render. My code is below:

```
// Adds a skybox around the content
  var loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
  loader.setPath( 'images/skybox/' );

  var textureCube = loader.load( [
       'sky1.jpg', 'sky2.jpg',
        'sky3.jpg', 'sky4.jpg',
         'sky5.jpg', 'sky6.jpg'
     ] );

  var skyMaterials = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, envMap: 
  textureCube } );
  var skyBoxGeom = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10000, 10000, 10000, 1, 1, 1);
  skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( skyBoxGeom, skyMaterials );
  skyBox.position.set(0, 25.1, 0);
  scene.add( skyBox );
```

I do not have any error messages in the console, but the cube is not rendering at all. The other objects in the scene render normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.background` property of `THREE.Scene()` straight, as it accepts cube textures.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 300 );
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

var loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
loader.setCrossOrigin( "" );
loader.setPath( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/cube/skybox/' );

var cubeTexture = loader.load( [
  'px.jpg', 'nx.jpg',
  'py.jpg', 'ny.jpg',
  'pz.jpg', 'nz.jpg'
] );

scene.background = cubeTexture;

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: I didn't see this reply until now, and I was still working on it, lol. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the [Three.js Master file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/archive/master.zip)? It has all the examples in working order.  So all the examples you see on the [Examples Page](https://threejs.org/examples/) are there along with support files, textures assets etc.  This way, you can start your project with a working example and build from there.  You will need to run them from your local server (from your post, I gather you already know this).
There are a few examples that may help you like [Panorama Cube](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_panorama_cube).  In the examples directory of the download, you will find a file called '**webgl_panorama_cube.html**' that will be your local copy of this example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that does not appear to be the same thing. It does use an array, but it pulls the same image 6 times from what I see. Am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, I see now that the texture contains all 6 images in one jpg. How does that change the syntax when there are 6 separate images?

Comment: It is hard to debug a project without having the whole thing up an running in front of me.  My point was that there is a very large number of working examples to pull from.  I can remember seeing three or four variations on cube maps and panorama backgrounds.  You may need to look through them and find the example that best fits your need.

Comment: Here is an example skybox that may be closer to what you need:  https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_backgrounds

Comment: You can take a look at this too: https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-skybox